# Is there a good database backend in Django for Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to use DynamoDB for my next Django project. I have found implentation to store session data into DynamoDB, but is there backend implementation for Django to store all the database data?

Comment: Don't know of one but it'd likely be a fork of django non-rel. I've found normally it's better to use plain django than trying to use non-rel.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there are any Django DynamoDB projects out there that allow you to use the Django ORM while using DynamoDB underneath.

But depending on your case, you may still be able to simply ignore the ORM portion of Django and use DynamoDB directly (via boto or PynamoDB or similar ).

In my case, I use a mix. I keep all my users and other models that are mostly read only on Postgres (RDS) and Django ORM, but use DynamoDB for models that require heavy writes ( using pynamodb).

I still get to use the views, templates or even add an API via Django-rest-framework. What I lose is the admin pages ( that I don't need for these models ) and other features the ORM gives you but I have been happy with the result anyway.

Comment: I have been taking the same approach. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used this one personally but the guy who developed it is a frequent contributor to boto and his work has always been of high quality.

https://bitbucket.org/maxnoel/dynamodb-mapper

Comment: Actually, I guess this doesn't really solve your problem.  At least not directly.  This project provides an ORM mapper on top of DynamoDB but it doesn't provide a Django backend.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a project on github called [django dyanmodb sessions](https://github.com/gtaylor/django-dynamodb-sessions) which looks incomplete (no closing of sessions), but promising.  Here is a [link to an announcement](http://gc-taylor.com/blog/2012/02/15/django-dynamodb-sessions-ready/) from one of the authors.

Comment: Looks like the repo is archived and there doesn't seem like there is a maintainer willing to take it on