# Django Design Pattern with NoSQL DynamoDB

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

This is a general design question as to how to best implement **DynamoDB** (or NoSQL/Key-Value in general) with the **Django ORM** for a rather large project with many django apps in it. I am planning on using this **in conjunction with a regular SQL** DB as well for the more "mundane" and not speed dependant queries.

I've found some good insights in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35686143/11829999) already but I am wondering how this works in general as I have not used NoSQL DBs before. I am planning on using the [PyNamoDB](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/) interface as it seems the most recommended and tested.

**I primarily require DynamoDB (KV-pair) for 1 or 2 tables that can potentially have several millions of "rows" written per day and then increasingly queried the same (high read&write traffic). Something that may eventually be too heavy on a "traditional" SQL table and where a "model" with a single table data structure isn't really appropriate.**

Does anyone have experience on this topic especially relating the following questions:

- If the "traditional" Django model setup (`models.Model`) does no longer apply I assume and anything like using `models.Manager` and `Queryset` are out the question? If so then this perpetuates all the way through to using forms, views and by extension even templates? What is a recommended design pattern here?
- From the above question: how do "Models" that are DynamoDB only, work in general within the Django ORM? Is everything through PynamoDB read/write commands followed up through a custom implementation then?
- Registering Admin pages for any DynamoDB models won't work (easily) I assume?
- Any [Django Model Field Types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/) are then also obsolete/invalid for NoSQL/DynamoDB?
- While I am not planning on using MongoDB I still had a look for answers in the [*django-pymongo* repo](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/django-pymongo). What confused me is that the (only & default) registered DB in [settings.py](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/django-pymongo/blob/main/MyFirstDjangoProj/settings.py) is through djongo/pymongo and then [models.py in "myfirstapp"](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/django-pymongo/blob/main/myfirstapp/models.py) simply uses `class Employee(models.Model)` ? So am I right to assume that in this case djongo/pymongo "translates" this and still allows for the Django ORM to be functional? Something that PynamoDB/DynamoDB won't facilitate?
- Anything else I forgot that might be an important design decision here?